# apache config to redirect https to http weblogic module

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, https, weblogic

I have 3 Machines which I am configuring this way to work.

**MachineA**(https) -> **MachineB**(reverseproxy) -> **MachineC**(App)

**MachineA** - The public facing load balancer where SSL certificate is installed
**MachineB** - Apache http server to which the request from MachineA will be redirected and will be forwarded to Application server using mod_wls
**MachineC** - Weblogic Application server where app is deployed

I have configured my **MachineB** http config this way:

```
LoadModule weblogic_module modules/mod_wl.so
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R]

<IfModule mod_weblogic.c>
    ProxyPreserveHost   On
    RewriteEngine       On
    WebLogicCluster wlsrv:7001
    Debug ALL
    MatchExpression /
    DebugConfigInfo ON
    WLLogFile /var/log/wlproxy-qa.log
 <Location /console>
    SetHandler weblogic-handler
    ProxyPass http://wlsrv:7001/console
    ProxyPassReverse http://wlsrv:7001/console
 </Location>
 <Location /App1>
    SetHandler weblogic-handler
    ProxyPass http://wlsrv:7001/App1
    ProxyPassReverse http://wlsrv:7001/App1
 </Location>
</IfModule>
```

The requests are coming to access the first webpage from application, but after that the URI is not getting forwarded correctly and giving 400.

Is my configuration of **MachineB** is correct to handle this ?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing proxypass directives belonging to mod_proxy with directives that belong to weblogic plugin through the handler.

The correct config is like follows (adapting your config):

```
LoadModule weblogic_module modules/mod_wl.so
<IfModule mod_weblogic.c>
    WebLogicCluster wlsrv:7001
    Debug ALL
    DebugConfigInfo ON
    WLLogFile /var/log/wlproxy-qa.log
 <Location /console>
    SetHandler weblogic-handler
 </Location>
 <Location /App1>
    SetHandler weblogic-handler
 </Location>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but as I am appending one string before application, it worked for me like this:`ProxyPass /pod/wlsapp1 http://wlssrv1:7001/wlsapp1
    ProxyPassReverse /pod/wlsapp1 http://wlssrv1:7001/wlsapp1` with Location it never worked.

Comment: my config looks like as here now https://serverfault.com/questions/912862/reverseproxy-to-connect-multiple-backened-server-from-single-virtual-host